# how to assign random float number in python

Tags: python, math, numpy

I used this code to generate xyz coordinates.

```
from random import *

uniqcoord = [7.63, 28.05, 66.36]         # my file contains 100 such list of points

for i in range(10):
    i = i + 1
    x,y,z = uniqcoord
    x1,y1,z1 = (uniform(x[0]-3.5,x[0]+3.5), uniform(y[1]-3.5,y[1]+3.5), uniform(z[2]-3.5,z[2]+3.5))
    print i, '\t', x1,y1,z1
```

When i run this program its showing error.
when i run this program with hole numbers it work.
how to resolve????

Comment: "its showing error" doesnt tell us much ...

Comment: `x`,`y`,`z` are numbers. But you use them in code like `x[0]`. why?

Comment: You seem to be quite confused on a lot of syntax. An example is how you increment i in the for loop, when it auto-increments. You also try to index into an integer. It might help to review the basics of Python and programming in general.

Comment: When you say `x,y,z = uniqcoord` you are assigning 7.63 to `x` 28.05 to `y` and 66.36 to `z`,you are NOT creating 3 lists.

Comment: You can use `range(1,11)` so that you don't need to increment `i` before using it.

Answer (score 3):

Your `x`, `y`, `z` are `float`, not `list`. So your can't have `x[0]` and such. You will get a `no attribute` or `typeerror` for that.

Answer (score 1):

You're incorrectly using x,y,z in the `x1,y1,z1` line. See what I've done below;

```
from random import *

uniqcoord = [7.63, 28.05, 66.36]         # my file contains 100 such list of points

for i in range(10):
    i=i+1
    x,y,z = uniqcoord
    x1,y1,z1 = (uniform(uniqcoord[0]-3.5,uniqcoord[0]+3.5), uniform(uniqcoord[1]-3.5,uniqcoord[1]+3.5), uniform(uniqcoord[2]-3.5,uniqcoord[2]+3.5))
    print i, '\t', x1,y1,z1
```

x[0] does not exist, but uniqcoord[0] = x because uniqcoord = [x,y,z], and so on.

Result:

```
1   5.86941266341 29.4004245806 67.1323961576
2   6.38143060206 29.7045813689 69.4867869245
3   5.55280335095 29.9472835241 63.7388152633
4   10.5607637875 26.6269381673 69.5256503601
5   7.29826364813 28.5740308696 65.2122276564
6   8.24134391937 30.880058802 69.8445734597
7   10.246919304 27.9240839326 64.9480054046
8   8.26957559527 28.5700768795 63.996117793
9   5.88677020227 30.0621250245 63.7431176092
10  8.98100830174 27.3378753286 63.1329446911
```

I *think* this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes I got it.  Thanks to all.

Comment: Be sure to accept an answer. :)

Comment: @lsb123 Thanks! If I answered your question adequately, please accept mine as your answer.